# How do I change the permissions of all files of one extension using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions

I'm trying to write a script that changes permissions based on file extensions and command line arguments given.

The command line arguments that will be given are:

1. directory
2. file extension
3. u/g/o (only one)
4. r/w/x (only one)

for example, if you give .txt and u r, it will give all the users read permissions to files that end in .txt.

I know how to change the permissions based on the arguments given, but I'm not sure how to make it only apply to files of a certain extension in a folder

Comment: You need an *option parser* like `getops` or something similar or roll your own parser.

Comment: I don't understand from your question, at which point you are stuck: Parsing the command line arguments, or implementing the algorithm?

Comment: Please show what you tried so far and explain what was wrong with it. You could also maybe visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Example of wise advice you can find there: "_Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._".

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  If you have the directory in `$d` and the extension in `$e`, why would `"$d/*$e"` not work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following command:

```bash
find /folder/path/ -name "*.txt" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

where `/folder/path`, `*.txt` and `+x` must be customized by you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
shopt -s globstar
chmod u+r /path/to/directory/**/*.txt
```

Bash manual of `globstar`:

> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.

Of course, customize the arguments of the `chmod` command to suit other needs.